# Getting day and time from date field with time, with field calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, field-calculator

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 and have a field containing a date and time
I need to get the day of the week based on my date field
and also when the same field that contains date and time

I need to do this from the field calculator

example

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to do this in Excel / OpenOffice Calc before you import the spreadsheet into ArcMap? There is a function in Excel called `weekday` that does this. If you need something else you need to be more specific with your question.

Comment: I agree with @dru87, but you can use the datetime module eg.

Answer (score 3):

In your new field use the field calculator with the following script code in the Field Calculator window:

```python
def dayOfWeek(dField):
    dow = datetime.datetime.strptime(dField , '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').strftime('%A')
    return dow

dayOfWeek(!DateField!)
```

The `%A` returns the day of the week, as in Monday, Tuesday, etc.  This can be changed per your requirements using the codes shown on **[this page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)**.

The date format in `strptime()` may need to be modified to match your date settings - the geoprocessing results window can help debug what kind of date is being passed if it does fail.

[image]